# Laravel 5.4 Session removing variable on page reload

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.4

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function processLogin(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $email = $request->get('email', '');
        $password = $request->get('password', '');

        $token = $this->_loginService->processLoginAttempt($email, $password);

        Session::put('access_token', $token);
        Session::save();

        return redirect()->route('portals');
    }

    public function showPortals(Request $request)
    {
        dd(Session::get('access_token'));
    }

    ....

}
```

The `middleware` group for the request is set to `web`.
Upon executing the `processLogin()` controller method, and being redirected to `showPortals()`, the `access_token` is dumped on the screen. However, upon refreshing the page, that session variable is cleared.

Strange thing is, instead of doing a `redirect()` within `processLogin()` and instead I do a `dd()`, and then access `showPortals()` endpoint, the session token persists as it should, even upon refreshing the page multiple times.

I read somewhere that `Session::save()` takes a while to save (perhaps it is asynchronous?) which might lead to this behaviour?

I tried every other method, but the session variable is not persisting on page reload.

Comment: this code is wrong

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample of code . when saving a session u have to give the key, data and duration or you can save it forever if you like.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
        {
            public function processLogin(LoginRequest $request)
            {
                $email = $request->email;
                $password = $request->password;

                $token = $this->_loginService->processLoginAttempt($email, $password);

    //this will save your token for 24 hours
                Session::put('access_token', $token, 60*24);

                return redirect()->route('portals');
            }

            public function showPortals(Request $request)
            {
                dd(Session::get('access_token'));
            }

            ....

        }
```